# React - adding className to Link component, ESLint error

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm using ESLint to lint my React app, and for a `Link` component with a `className`, I get the following warning:

`error  Prop 'className' is forbidden on Components  react/forbid-component-props`

I get what that's all about and I realize that I could just turn this rule off, but I'd rather do things the 'right' way...

This is my component -

```
<Link
    className="edit_link"
    to={`/user/${this.state.user.id}/edit`}>
    Edit
</Link>
```

and it all works as it should... but is there a best practice for this sort of situation? For components that I create, I can, of course, place `className`s on the outermost DOM node in the component, but how should that be handled for components link `Link`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-component-props.md). You can either turn this rule off or place the `className` on DOM nodes.

Comment: Thanks - I get that, but I'm looking for a 'third' way - can I leave the rule on but set a `className` on a component where I don't have control over the DOM nodes?

Comment: It is just a warning. And as stated,  it only `prevents passing of props that add lots of complexity (className, style) to Components`. You don't need to bypass all warning perfectly :). (At least from my opinion)

Comment: Cool, thanks. Yes, I'm with you, I don't necessarily feel that all warnings must be abided by... but I was unfamiliar with this issue and wanted to be sure there wasn't some 'best practice' that I was overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of either `React` or `React-router-dom` are you using? Using `className` tag in the `Link` component works perfectly.

Just like this:

```
<Link to={this.props.link} className="whateverClassName">Home</Link>
```

Using `16.3.1` version for `React` and `5.1.2` version for `React-router-dom`.